# How to display the block after clicking command button

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, pageblock, outputpanel

```
<apex:outputPanel id="filterBlock">

    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!isLoadPage}">
    <div style="width:35%;" id="maindiv">
    <apex:pageblocksection >
    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputlabel value="Account Filters" style="font-weight:bold"/>
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>


    <apex:pageblockSectionItem >

    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv()" id="showlink" style="display:none;" >HideFilter</a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv()" id="hidelink" >ShowFilter</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;


    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageblocksection> 
    </div>

        <apex:outputPanel id="showblock" style="display:none;">
           <apex:pageblockSection columns="3">
            <apex:repeat value="{!filterArray}" var="a">
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!a.label}"/>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!a.SearchValue}" id="searchTextId"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
              </apex:repeat> 
              <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                 <a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" id="clearValue" style="display:none;"> Clear Filter </a>  

              </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="hideblock" style="display:none;">

        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:outputPanel>
function toggleDiv() {
    $("[id$=showblock]").toggle();
    $("[id$=showlink]").toggle();
    $("[id$=hideblock]").toggle();
    $("[id$=hidelink]").toggle();
    $("[id$=clearValue]").toggle();

    }


    function clearValue() {
        $("[id$=searchTextId]").val('');       
    }
```

I am having a command button called `Search` which displays the output panel on clicking. On clicking the link `Show Filter` , it will display the inputtext field.( It is similar to the standard filter search doing in the salesforce). But once i enter the values in the filter field and doing the search , i want the `showblock` content to be displayed there. Instead the block is vanishing off and again it is making me to click on the `show filter` link to display the filter field block. Please any one help me out

Comment: You don't show us where "Show Filter" is in your DOM. All I see is "showlink", an outputPanel with an Id of "showblock", another toggle for "hidelink" (no match to anything, and an outputPanel  with an id of "hideblock". You've either not shown us the relevant code or don't have your Id's matched correctly in your code.

Comment: I have added the script function which is toggling the block using the hyperlink

Comment: Where is your search button code where you are performing search and rendering the panel?

Comment: Depending on your search button code, this is generally NOT the way to be doing a show/hide with VF. Using `apex:commandLink` and the `action` attribute you can use native Ajax capabilities without calling JS to toggle visibility with the onClick while also triggering the reRender. See the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm.